# I'm trying to use random function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, random

```
var x = 1 + Math.Random() % 9;
if (x==1)
    // do something
else if (x==2) 
    // do something else
```

I used this line — `(1 + Math.Random() % 9)` — in C++ to get a number between 1 and 9, but in JavaScript I'm getting a different result.

Comment: Note that it's `Math.random` not `Math.Random` (note the lower case `r`).

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` returns a value between `0` and `1`, so instead using the modulo operator you need to use a multiplication.

```
1 + (Math.random() * 9);
```

Finally, you should round or `.floor()` that value

```
var x = Math.floor( 1 + ( Math.random() * 9 ) );
```

or, shorter

```
var x = ~~( 1 + ( Math.random() * 9 ) );
```

Comment: Note that you are using uppercase in your first example on Random, use lowercase ;-)

Comment: @SimonEdström: oh yes thanks, never copy&paste (note myself).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Math.Random()` function in JavaScript. It's `Math.random()`. Note the capitalization.

To get a random number between a certain minimum and maximum value, do this:

```
var min = 1, max = 9;
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

**Further reading:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the `Math.random` function returns a number between 0 and 1.  If you want to get a number between 1 and 9 you'll have to work with it a bit.

```
var number = ((Math.random() * 10) | 0) % 9 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a result between 0 and 9

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*9)
```

And by the way, jQuery is a javascript framework. Math is a native javascript function